# What all does AppScan scan with JavaScript?

Tags: javascript, security, bluemix-app-scan

I can't find any good documentation that lists what all IBM's AppScan Source scans for JavaScript projects.  I've looked through many of their PDFs and websites but haven't found anything that details what it covers and reviews.

- What does AppScan claim to to find in JavaScript?
- Can it handle projects with Angular, Jquery, and other 3rd party libraries? Any that it can't handle?

Answer (score 2):

The Javascript scanner in AppScan Source supports normal client side javascript apis, MobileFirst apis, and a part of jQuery, Cordova, html5, and Backbone apis. Unfortunately no AngularJS yet

Comment: Thanks! Is there any documentation on it?  What sort of vulnerabilities does it look for?

Answer (score 0):

Some information about improvements of AppScan Source's Javascript features can be found from AppScan Source's new version release notes, for example

**AppScan Source 9.0:**

*Performance is now improved when scanning JavaScript.*

http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg24037073

**Appscan Source 9.0.1:**

*Enhanced accuracy for JavaScript analysis:
Pattern-based static analysis results for JavaScript are now included.
Preliminary support for Backbone.js and Require.js (currently disabled).
Various bug fixes.*

http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg24038332

The vulnerabilities it look for include common web security vulnerabilities for example Cross-Site Scripting, DataLeakage, URL redirect, OS injection, SQL injection etc.

It currently supports normal client side javascript apis, MobileFirst apis, and a part of jQuery, Cordova, html5, and Backbone apis.